# checkServerIdentity Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssl, lets-encrypt

**Short question:**

what is going wrong with the checkServerIdentity?

if I turn the option off then I can connect! But I would like to use this option!

---

**long question**

running mongodb 3.2.6

I made a db user

```
use db
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "user",
      pwd: "pass",
      roles: [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "db" }
      ]
    }
)
```

My mongod.conf looks like this

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true

processManagement:
  fork: true  
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  

net:
  port: 27017 
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/mongod-PEMKeyFile.pem
    CAFile: /etc/letsencrypt/mongod-CAFile.pem
```

I start `mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf`

Then I run my node.js script

```
require(__dirname+'/../node_modules/mongodb').MongoClient.connect(
    'mongodb://user:pass@127.0.0.1:27017/db?ssl=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=db'
    ,   {server:{
         sslValidate:true
    ,    checkServerIdentity:true
    ,    sslCA:[require('fs').readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/identrust-root-download-x3.pem')]
    ,    sslKey:require('fs').readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem')
    ,    sslCert:require('fs').readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/mongod-sslCert.pem')
         }}
,   function(e,db){
    console.log(e,db);
    });
```

Just shows error

```
{ [MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect]
   name: 'MongoError',
   message: 'failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect' }
```

> Note: It connects fine if I turn off ssl in the mongod.conf and the node.js script!

There is no info in the mongod.log

```
2016-08-03T19:23:26.995+0200 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=25307 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=xxxx
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-08-03T19:23:27.012+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { port: 27017, ssl: { CAFile: "/etc/letsencrypt/mongod-CAFile.pem", PEMKeyFile: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/mongod-PEMKeyFile.pem", mode: "requireSSL" } }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, security: { authorization: "enabled" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2016-08-03T19:23:27.047+0200 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /var/lib/mongo created by the 'mmapv1' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'mmapv1'.
2016-08-03T19:23:27.059+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-03T19:23:27.059+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Readahead for /var/lib/mongo is set to 4096KB
2016-08-03T19:23:27.059+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          We suggest setting it to 256KB (512 sectors) or less
2016-08-03T19:23:27.059+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/readahead
2016-08-03T19:23:27.059+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongo/journal
2016-08-03T19:23:27.060+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2016-08-03T19:23:27.364+0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2016-08-03T19:23:27.365+0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-08-03T19:23:27.366+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-08-03T19:23:27.389+0200 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/var/lib/mongo/diagnostic.data'
2016-08-03T19:23:27.389+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017 ssl
2016-08-03T19:23:27.390+0200 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
```

How can I debug this? that error tells me nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-788

Lucas Hrabovsky added a comment - Aug 04 2016 05:38:18 PM GMT+0000

> Looking at the implementation for checkServerIdentity, this is the callback passed to `tls.connect()`.
>   Passing `checkServerIdentity: true` per your example is not required as this is the default value for this option and should only be specified as `checkServerIdentity: false` or a custom callback.

benzmuircroft@gmail.com Benz Muircroft added a comment - Aug 04 2016 06:55:04 PM GMT+0000

> Feedback:
>   That seems really odd that setting it to true would prevent it from connecting! shouldn't `checkServerIdentity:true` just be ignored or at lease have a relevant warning/error
>
> the current output error offers no hint:
>
> `{ [MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect] name: 'MongoError', message: 'failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect' }`
>
> Ps: this is using MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6 I have another sever with MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8 and setting `checkServerIdentity:true` on 3.2.8 does not affect connecting in any way! (both servers are using node.js mongodb 2.2.4) its very weird that only one server is affected.
>
> Thanks!